# DataDog alert includes filtered out environment tag

Tags: terraform, notifications, production-environment, datadog, observability

I have a DataDog query alert like so:

> min(last_5m):sum:my_service.verification.failure{service:"my_service" AND env:"production"} by {region,env} >= 1

And I enabled the include tags in the alert title feature.

The problem is that the notification title includes the **env:development** tag along with the production one, like so:

> [P4] [Triggered on {env:development,env:production,region:australia-...

This makes no sense at all bc I'm filtering the env tag precisely to exclude development!

Am I doing something wrong?

Removing env from the `by {region,env}` expression resolves the issue, but does not include the env tag based to the alert notification title.

I expect my alerts to not include the `env:development` in the title, nor in the tag template for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that DataDog can assign more than a single 'env' tag to a metric.

We found out that the env tag was being populated in several places in the infrastructure (inside the service and the external dd collector to be exact).